# What is private.hpp of opencv?? Which module contains the private.hpp file?

Tags: c++, opencv

I downloaded the opencv 411 version of Master Branch and Extra module sources.

First, the extra module was copied into the master and set configuration as msvs2015 x64 as a cmake.

Then we opened Opencv.sln and build an install project.

Project build was succeeded.

Then I get a test code from an opencv tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/tutorial.html

```
#include <opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp>

#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/private.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static const char* keys =
{ "{@image_path | | Image path }" };

static void help()
{
  cout << "\nThis example shows the functionalities of lines extraction " << "furnished by BinaryDescriptor class\n"
           << "Please, run this sample using a command in the form\n" << "./example_line_descriptor_lines_extraction <path_to_input_image>" << endl;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /* get parameters from comand line */
  CommandLineParser parser( argc, argv, keys );
  String image_path = parser.get<String>( 0 );

  if( image_path.empty() )
  {
        help();
        return -1;
  }

  /* load image */
  cv::Mat imageMat = imread( image_path, 1 );
  if( imageMat.data == NULL )
  {
        std::cout << "Error, image could not be loaded. Please, check its path" << std::endl;
  }

  /* create a ramdom binary mask */
  cv::Mat mask = Mat::ones( imageMat.size(), CV_8UC1 );

  /* create a pointer to a BinaryDescriptor object with deafult parameters */
  Ptr<BinaryDescriptor> bd = BinaryDescriptor::createBinaryDescriptor();

  /* create a structure to store extracted lines */
  vector<KeyLine> lines;

  /* extract lines */
  bd->detect( imageMat, lines, mask );

  /* draw lines extracted from octave 0 */
  cv::Mat output = imageMat.clone();
  if( output.channels() == 1 )
        cvtColor( output, output, COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
        KeyLine kl = lines[i];
        if( kl.octave == 0)
        {
          /* get a random color */
          int R = ( rand() % (int) ( 255 + 1 ) );
          int G = ( rand() % (int) ( 255 + 1 ) );
          int B = ( rand() % (int) ( 255 + 1 ) );

          /* get extremes of line */
          Point pt1 = Point( kl.startPointX, kl.startPointY );
          Point pt2 = Point( kl.endPointX, kl.endPointY );

          /* draw line */
          line( output, pt1, pt2, Scalar( B, G, R ), 5 );
        }

  }

  /* show lines on image */
  imshow( "Lines", output );
  waitKey();
}
```

But compile failed, and the error message is as follows:

> Opencv2/core/private.hpp file not found.

When I checked, the private.hpp file was not created in the install/include folder within the build folder path.

Perhaps, when checking options of the cmake, a missing module appears.
But I don't know which module to create a private.hpp file.

If you know, please reply.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is outdated anyway and should not work with opencv version 4+ since some of the classes are wrapped inside namespaces. You can use below code.

```
#include <opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static const char* keys =
{ "{@image_path | | Image path }" };

static void help()
{
  cout << "\nThis example shows the functionalities of lines extraction " << "furnished by BinaryDescriptor class\n"
           << "Please, run this sample using a command in the form\n" << "./example_line_descriptor_lines_extraction <path_to_input_image>" << endl;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /* get parameters from comand line */
  CommandLineParser parser( argc, argv, keys );
  String image_path = parser.get<String>( 0 );

  if( image_path.empty() )
  {
        help();
        return -1;
  }

  /* load image */
  cv::Mat imageMat = imread( image_path, 1 );
  if( imageMat.data == NULL )
  {
        std::cout << "Error, image could not be loaded. Please, check its path" << std::endl;
  }

  /* create a ramdom binary mask */
  cv::Mat mask = Mat::ones( imageMat.size(), CV_8UC1 );

  /* create a pointer to a BinaryDescriptor object with deafult parameters */
  Ptr<cv::line_descriptor::BinaryDescriptor> bd = cv::line_descriptor::BinaryDescriptor::createBinaryDescriptor();

  /* create a structure to store extracted lines */
  vector<cv::line_descriptor::KeyLine> lines;

  /* extract lines */
  bd->detect( imageMat, lines, mask );

  /* draw lines extracted from octave 0 */
  cv::Mat output = imageMat.clone();
  if( output.channels() == 1 )
        cvtColor( output, output, COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
        cv::line_descriptor::KeyLine kl = lines[i];
        if( kl.octave == 0)
        {
          /* get a random color */
          int R = ( rand() % (int) ( 255 + 1 ) );
          int G = ( rand() % (int) ( 255 + 1 ) );
          int B = ( rand() % (int) ( 255 + 1 ) );

          /* get extremes of line */
          Point pt1 = Point( kl.startPointX, kl.startPointY );
          Point pt2 = Point( kl.endPointX, kl.endPointY );

          /* draw line */
          line( output, pt1, pt2, Scalar( B, G, R ), 5 );
        }

  }

  /* show lines on image */
  imshow( "Lines", output );
  waitKey();
}
```

Edit: I also did not know what was private.hpp, did some search and found this inside private.hpp:

> this is a private header which should not be used from outside of the
>   OpenCV library

So it is probably a file designed to used by other opencv library files only and should not be used from user code. [Link to file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp)